# Forming a soap request with Multiple records

Tags: apex, batch, callout, soap

I am trying to create a batch class which would query a list of records and makes an apex callout to an external system.

How can I go about writing this batch class? For a single request I can write a code like this:

```
abc.webservice wm = new abc.webservice();
wm.endpoint_x = 'http://xyz.com';
wm.inputHttpHeaders_x = new Map<String, String>();
wm.inputHttpHeaders_x.put('Username','user');
wm.inputHttpHeaders_x.put('Password','pass');
String res = wm.testFlow('Hello');
system.debug('******' + res);
```

How can I add the list of request which I get using a batch class's start() method. How can add those records and their field values in a single request here?

Comment: It will depend on the external system and the WSDL they provide. What is the format of the object they require for an Array of records?

Comment: @Eric when I convert the wsdl to apex I see only one method which takes an argument as an object. processOrder(orderinput ord).. that's where the invoke method is. How can I call this method with a list or array of orderinput? Should I make changes to wsdl so that the method which has invoke method takes in a list instead of a single object? Thanks

Comment: If there is no method in the wsdl then the service provider may have not made it available. You can't just add a method to the wsdl and expect it to work.

Comment: @Eric Thanks I am going to ask the service provider to change the wsdl. I will not be doing the change on my own. Your help is always appreciated here.